# Pywinauto - how to get the 'value' property of an element (progress bar) which will dynamically changing

Tags: python, wpf, automation, pywinauto, inspect

Am trying to automate wpf application backend=uia, for progress bar i need to get the dynamically changing "value" attribute, but when i used window_text() am getting '',then i tried to pass the control in this wrapper `pywinauto.application.controls.uia_controls.UIAElementInfo(ctrl).name` getting this error `TypeError("UIAElementInfo object can be initialized " + \ "with integer or IUIAutomationElement instance only!`) and finally tried to pass the element in the following Progresswrapper class `pywinauto.controls.common_controls.ProgressWrapper(element_info).get_position()` am getting element_info should be hwndwrapper.

[image]

this is my code app.py

1. start the app.exe

   ```
   app = pywinauto.application.Application(backend='uia').start('app.exe')
   ```
2. identifying the window

   ```
   wind = app.window(auto_id="someid")
   ```
3. finding the progress bar control

   ```
   ctrl = wind.window(auto_id='progress')
   ```
4. getting the text of the control progress bar

   ```
   ctrl.window_text()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Method `ctrl.get_value()` is what you need. You shouldn't try to create wrappers manually if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: What if it doesn't work? For `ListItemWrapper` I get `AttributeError: 'ListItemWrapper' object has no attribute 'value'`. However, Inspect.exe shows correct Value.

Comment: Method `.get_value()` and property `Value` have different names. Please edit your question with more code you're trying. Pywinauto method names don't have to be the same as in Inspect.exe.

Comment: Also please switch Inspect.exe to UI Automation mode from MSAA.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Yes, `get_value` works fine, thanks!